# Hide duplicates rows SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I have query:

```
SELECT TermMsg.TRM_ID, 
   upper(TermMsg.TRM_LOCALE_CODE) as TRM_LOCALE_CODE, 
   TermMsg.TRM_NAME, 
   TermMsg.TRM_DESCRIPTION, 
   upper(substr(TRM_NAME,1,1)) AS LETTER, 
   (Term.TRM_PUBLISHED) AS PUBLISHED,
   tga.GRP_ID
FROM EPBS_DATA.GLS_TERM_LOC TermMsg, EPBS_DATA.GLS_TERM Term left join 
EPBS_DATA.GLS_TERM_GROUP_ASSIGNMENT tga
on Term.TRM_ID = tga.TRM_ID
WHERE TermMsg.TRM_ID = Term.TRM_ID and TermMsg.TRM_NAME IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY TRM_NAME;
```

But i have duplicates row if one Term have more one tga.GRP_ID. How i can hide it? Thanks!
[image: Result screen]

Comment: Before anyone can answer how you should hide the apparent duplicate, you should specify acceptable criteria for hiding duplicates. For example, the last column in your query is GRP_ID ... in the case you cited (where TRM_ID is 16) you have 2 different GRP_ID values (6 and 2). If you want to remove duplicates, which of these duplicates should be hidden? The row with Group ID 6 or Group ID 2?

Comment: @nb1987 No difference. Can hide any lines that there was one

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways you can hide. If it doesn't matter what GRP_ID value is hidden, then perhaps you do not need to include any GRP_ID column. In that case you could remove the GRP_ID column from your SELECT clause and do SELECT DISTINCT:

```
SELECT DISTINCT TermMsg.TRM_ID, 
upper(TermMsg.TRM_LOCALE_CODE) as TRM_LOCALE_CODE, 
TermMsg.TRM_NAME, 
TermMsg.TRM_DESCRIPTION, 
upper(substr(TRM_NAME,1,1)) AS LETTER, 
(Term.TRM_PUBLISHED) AS PUBLISHED
FROM EPBS_DATA.GLS_TERM_LOC TermMsg, EPBS_DATA.GLS_TERM Term left join 
EPBS_DATA.GLS_TERM_GROUP_ASSIGNMENT tga
on Term.TRM_ID = tga.TRM_ID
WHERE TermMsg.TRM_ID = Term.TRM_ID and TermMsg.TRM_NAME IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY TRM_NAME;
```

However, if you really need to include at least some GRP_ID value, then you could use the [ROW_NUMBER() function](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions137.htm):

```
SELECT q.* 
FROM (
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY TermMsg.TRM_ID ORDER BY tga.GRP_ID)  AS ROWNUM, TermMsg.TRM_ID, 
upper(TermMsg.TRM_LOCALE_CODE) as TRM_LOCALE_CODE, 
TermMsg.TRM_NAME, 
TermMsg.TRM_DESCRIPTION, 
upper(substr(TRM_NAME,1,1)) AS LETTER, 
(Term.TRM_PUBLISHED) AS PUBLISHED,
tga.GRP_ID
FROM EPBS_DATA.GLS_TERM_LOC TermMsg, EPBS_DATA.GLS_TERM Term left join 
EPBS_DATA.GLS_TERM_GROUP_ASSIGNMENT tga
on Term.TRM_ID = tga.TRM_ID
WHERE TermMsg.TRM_ID = Term.TRM_ID and TermMsg.TRM_NAME IS NOT NULL
) q
WHERE q.ROWNUM = 1
ORDER BY q.TRM_NAME;
```

I don't have a database with your schema to test against but I believe that query should work. This is a fairly common pattern in Oracle when you need to remove duplicates where a SELECT DISTINCT won't work. You can see that your query needs to be embedded as a sub-query; then, the outer query selects where the ROWNUM is equal to 1. The key is that it is being partitioned by the TRM_ID column -- basically, you PARTITION BY whichever columns that you want to be unique in your final output.

(If you do not want the ROWNUM in the final output, then instead of SELECT q.* you can select each column that you want individually from the sub-query.)

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to nb1987's approach using ROW_NUMBER would be to use a GROUP BY on all the output columns except the one which is causing you undesirable duplicates (GRP_ID). In the SELECT, you could use a MIN/MAX with the GRP_ID if you really want the column, but don't care about which row is selected (why?!).

This may perform better or worse than nb1987's solution so it would make sense to try it with your data to be sure.